# How to display data in a new page from the database after doing some postprocessing on the new data

Tags: python, django, forms

Django newbie here, I created a few forms which correctly stores them in the database, and then used django signals to do some post-processing on the latest data. Now I want to display that data on a new page, so how do I go about that ? Consider my django app takes in the weight,height, lifestyle habits of patients, and then on the next page, show that data in a tabular form, but also displays how close they are to healthy eating habits, their BMI, fat percentage etc.

Comment: Is your question about how to query the data and show them in template?

Comment: Not really, like I said I am able to show data perfectly, but now I want it to create a report based on data given in a form. Like you enter your personal details, and get a score card of how healthy your lifestyle is.